# Хэширование значений, хранящихся в таблице в определенном поле *пароль) в прямом виде

Tags: php, postgresql

Есть таблица, в которой, есть столбец password. Данные в этом столбце хранятся в прямом виде, например `moi_super_parol`. Мне необходимо пробежаться по всем записям и модифицировать каждую с помощью php функции `password_hash(_значение поля_, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такую задачу максимально элегантно и наименее ресурсоемко, допуская, что записей в таблице может быть много. Считывать значения селектом в массив `id => password_value` и потом обходить массив, апдейтить? Но если селект принесет в сетях 1.000.000 записей - никаких сервачных ресурсов не напасешься.. Что посоветуете? Спасибо

Comment: Ну так выясните сколько всего записей и обновляйте частями.

Comment: А покажите плиз как этот апдейт реализовать частями? Количество записей, разумеется, узнать не проблема

Comment: Select...  Limit 1000 и пока не закончатся?

Comment: А понял! Вы имеете ввиду частями селект, а я подумал про апдейт! Спасибо большое, попробую

Comment: используйте limit и offset для выборки подмножества